# Rotation of vector graphics

Tags: c#, winforms, vector, rotation

I have an application for drawing and editing vector graphics in WinForms

I have images, rectangles, ellipses, regions etc. and I know how to resize them by mouse move. But I don't know how to rotate them by mouse move.

I draw objects into Graphics.

I've tried this, but it didn't work.

```
g.TranslateTransform((float)(this.Rectangle.X + this.Rectangle.Width / 2), (float)(this.Rectangle.Y + this.Rectangle.Height / 2));
g.RotateTransform(this.Rotation);
g.TranslateTransform(-(float)(this.Rectangle.X + this.Rectangle.Width / 2), -(float)(this.Rectangle.Y + this.Rectangle.Height / 2));
//g.TranslateTransform(-(float)(rect.X + rect.Width / 2), -(float)(rect.Y + rect.Height / 2));

g.DrawImage(img, rect);

g.ResetTransform();
```

This didn't work, because I don't know how to find corners of objects in new (rotated) position, so I'm not able to resize that...

Comment: Please specify what framework you're using (WinForms), also in the tags

Comment: I don't know where the corners are and I can't resize it, even if I know were they are. Because the sizing is in in "not rotated" axes... if you understand :-)

Comment: You should post more of your code. What is 'this' pointing to? How are your objects being manipulated (dragged by corners)? Basically, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Maybe what you're asking is "How do I do a rotation while calling DrawImage?" which actually has nothing to do with vector graphics (as well as mouse moves).

Comment: I have all objects saved in my own structure DrawObject which has Rectangle that says position of the object. When I need to size any object, I check if the pointer is in the corner, then I resize the object. Everything works fine, but when I try to rotate objects with the code above, I can't find the corner and even if I'd find it, I'm not able to scale it properly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply high school trigonometry. There are lots of articles if you google "graphics.drawimage rotation"

But to start with, you should NOT be transforming the Graphics object itself. You are just looking to get the new bounding box of your image. To do this:

1. Take the bounding box of the image centered on the origin. Remember this is defined as three points for the benefit of DrawImage(Image, Point[])

   ```
   Point[] boundingBox = { new Point(-width /2, -height/2),
                           new Point(width/2, -height/2), 
                           new Point(-width/2, height/2) };
   ```
2. Use trig to rotate it. Feed each point through the following function:

   ```
   Point rotatePointAroundOrigin(Point point, float angleInDegrees) {
       float angle = angleInDegrees * Math.PI/180; // get angle in radians
       return new Point( point.X * Math.Cos(angle) - point.Y * Math.Sin(angle),
                         point.X * Math.Sin(angle) + point.Y * Math.Cos(angle));
   }
   ```
3. Translate the boundind box to where it has to go. Add the width/2 and height/2 to each of its points, plus whatever extra amount you want.
4. Call `DrawImage(image, boundingBox)`

Comment: thank you, I tried this, but when I try to draw with DrawImage(image, Point[]) it throws NotImplementedException...

Comment: googling "DrawImage NotImplementedException" yields http://blog.felipel.com/2009/06/notimplementedexception-in-graphics-drawimage/ Apparently, it is a bizarre behavior of DrawImage that it doesn't accept all Image classes.

Comment: Looks like I also made a mistake in the equation for rotating points. This can also cause a NotImplementedException if the resulting points are off and don't form a rectangle or parallelogram.

Comment: @MadMaxx (forgot to do the @ thing, so doing it now so you get a notification) Btw, I'll point out you can always do this for all four points of the image. You'll only pass the first three to DrawImage, but you'll use all four for your internal purpoposes.